# Modify parameter value of custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, refactoring

Is there any way to implement annotation in order to change his parameter value by itself?

For example:

I would like create custom RequestMapping annotation to get rid of some code duplicates.

Current code:

```
@RequestMapping("/this/is/duplicate/few/times/some")
public class SomeController {
}
```

And I want to create something like this

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RequestMapping()
public @interface CustomRequestMapping {

    String value() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String "/this/is/duplicate/few/times"+value();

}
```

In order to reduce Request Mapping value to this:

```
@CustomRequestMapping("/some")
public class SomeController {
}
```

Unfortunately I cant find way to make that compilable.
Or maybe there is a way to use AliasFor annotation to pass parameter into destination array. Something like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @RequestMapping()
    public @interface CustomRequestMapping {

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value{1}")
    String value() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value{0}")
    String prefixPath() default "/this/is/duplicate/few/times";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it seems is you are trying to make a subtype of an annotation and modify one of its attributes default value

Subtyping of annotation is not possible and [here](https://checkerframework.org/jsr308/specification/java-annotation-extensions.html) is the JSR stating the reason.

```
It complicates the annotation type system,and makes it much more difficult
to write “Specific Tools”.

“Specific Tools” — Programs that query known annotation types of arbitrary
 external programs. Stub generators, for example, fall into this category.
 These programs will read annotated classes without loading them into the 
 virtual machine, but will load annotation interfaces.
```

Comment: yeah. I've read that document when I was looking for solution. I was wondering is there any hack that will fill my requirement

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your duplication problem could be to extract a constant.

```
@Annotation(MyClass.FOO+"localValue")
public class MyClass
{
    public static final String FOO = "foo";
    ...
}
```

Comment: that is not what i meant. I was looking for solution to pass only "localValue" to annotation. In this case i will need to add MyClass.FOO by myself. I want it to be automaticly.